# Laravel save multiple record at once

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, eloquent

have a problem to save multiple records at once. This is my form

```
    {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'pipeline/save?return='.$return, 'class'=>'form-horizontal','files' => true , 'parsley-validate'=>'','novalidate'=>' ')) !!}
    @foreach($destinazioni as $destinazione)
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 text-left">
        <input type="text" name="destination[]" readonly class="form-control" value="{{ $destinazione }}"/>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
        <select name="target[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="Nessuna">Seleziona...</option>
        @foreach($campi->keys() as $target)
        <option value="{{ $target }}"> {{ $target }} </option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    @endforeach
        @if(!empty($profilo->set_attributi))
            @foreach($profilo->attributi as $attributo)
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 text-left">
                <input type="text" name="destination[]" readonly class="form-control" value="{{ $attributo->nome_opzione }}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
        <select name="target[]" class="form-control">
        <option value="Nessuna">Seleziona...</option>
        @foreach($campi->keys() as $target)
        <option value="{{ $target }}"> {{ $target }} </option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
<div style="clear:both"></div>  


                  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:5%">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 text-right">&nbsp;</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">  
                    <button type="submit" name="apply" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ><i class="icon-checkmark-circle2"></i> {{ Lang::get('core.sb_apply') }}</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ><i class="icon-bubble-check"></i> {{ Lang::get('core.sb_save') }}</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='{{ URL::to('pipeline?return='.$return) }}' " class="btn btn-warning btn-sm "><i class="icon-cancel-circle2 "></i>  {{ Lang::get('core.sb_cancel') }} </button>
                    </div>    

                  </div>

         {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is controller where i try to handle inserting of data:

```
$rules = $this->validateForm();
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);  
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $request = array('destination' => $request->input('destination'), 'target' => $request->input('target'));
        foreach ($request as $req) {
            $destination = new Pipeline;        
            $destination->destination = $req->destination;
            $destination->target = $req->target;
            $destination->save();
        }

        return Redirect::to('pipeline')->with('messagetext',\Lang::get('core.note_success'))->with('msgstatus','success');
```

But actually i get Try to get proprety of non object error. I have also tried with Pipeline::insert($data) method but it return wrong names of column error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If someone have this problem i just solved by implode and explode $request, and then loop with a for cicle. Quite easy.

```
function postSave( Request $request)
    {

        $rules = $this->validateForm();
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);  
        if ($validator->passes()) {
        $idz = implode(",", $request->input('destination'));
        $ids = explode(",", $idz);
        $tgz = implode(",", $request->input('target'));
        $tgs = explode(",", $tgz);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++)
        {
            $pipeline = new Pipeline;
            $pipeline->destination = $ids[$i];
            $pipeline->target = $tgs[$i];
            $pipeline->save();
            $i = $i++;

        }
```

Comment: this way is not good if you want to insert multiple records at once. because it can break the data flow when the "for"loop will reach a certain point.

Comment: in this case we have value of count $ids so we can iterate with for loop. If you have iterate all items you can use foreach instead

Comment: what happens if you have to insert 20 or 50 records at once. then your code will put a heavy load on the server because that's why I wrote this method is not good. in this case always use DB::insert($arrayOfArrays); as @EddyTheDove has mentioned

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to build arrays, just build an array with each object like

```
$arrays = [
    'destination' => $req->destination,
    'target'      => $req->target
]
```

Then insert all of your arrays in one go

```
DB::insert($arrayOfArrays);
```

If you still want to insert the way you are doing, try with

```
Pipeline::create([
    ...
]);
```

Comment: got this error preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Comment: Which method did you use?

Comment: created array and then DB::insert

Comment: Do you know the error line ? what's in that line. Try with the second method if you can.